# Why does monotone convergence theorem imply $\int_M \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} g_k(x)dx < \infty$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

[Here](http://planetmath.org/criterionforinterchangingsummationandintegration) it's claimed that for nonnegative $g_k$s whose sequence of partial sums is increasing

the monotone convergence theorem implies $$\int_M \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} g_k(x)dx < \infty$$

where $M$ is some measure space.

Comment: Define $f_n(x)$ to be the partial sums of $g_k$. Apply monotone convergence.

Comment: You may want to add the context that $\sum_k \int_M g_k < \infty$ as this certainly isn't true for any sequence whose partial sums are increasing.

Comment: @AlexR. I don't get it, what part of monotone convergence to apply?

Comment: @mavavilj Alex is defining $f_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n g_k(x)$ and suggesting that you apply monotone convergence to the sequence $f_1,f_2,\ldots$